# Getting Django's staticfiles includes working inside Vue.js .vue templates

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Django SPA built with Vue.js v2 / webpack.

I want to be able to use Django static template tags to add in references to images, etc inside Vue.js template `.vue` files.

Right now in my `base.html` template for Django:

```
{% load static %}
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- This works fine here! -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/test.css' %}" />
      ...
   </head>
   <body> 
      <div id="app">
        <!-- Vue.js app gets mounted here -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

and that is of course the HTML page I use for the SPA (single page application).

But when I try to use static tags in my `.vue` template files like so:

```
{% static 'js/test.js' %}
```

It doesn't work - it never gets interpolated because of course Django is server-side and Vue is client-side.

I want to keep using the staticfiles tags (and not hard links) because I use different storage backends for static files, media, and even from local/staging/prod environments.

Any ideas for how to handle this with Django/Vue.js? What's a good solution here to get staticfiles linking into templates clientside?

Answer (score -3):

A good solution? Separation of duties. Why should Django templates be involved at all? Your front end code can handle all rendering. Your back end can just serve up rest api endpoints.

Comment: That's hardly an answer. Have you used Django before? Mapping to static urls is pretty important.

Comment: I'm working on an application right now that is just that--Django on the backend and Vuejs on the frontend. The Django part is not concerned at all with rendering. I'm not using anything involving Django templates, static files, etc. All rendering is handled by the front end Vuejs code. My only point was that you need to question the decision to use Django templates.

Comment: How do you link to static assets like images? User uploaded files?

Comment: I'm not dealing with user uploaded files/media, but any other images are in `src\images` and will get picked up by webpack. Have you looked at the Vue documentation on backend intregration? https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html

Comment: did you get that working with collectstatic command? otherwise a bit hard to run on heroku, for example.

Comment: I don't need `collecstatic` because Django is not managing any of my static assets. I have two separate projects/repositories: frontend and backend. All static assets: images, css, javascript is in the frontend project. All the backend project does is serve api endpoints. Note that this means I'm also not using the Django admin. Any interaction with the backend database is handled through api calls from the frontend UI.

Comment: An answer should be directed at using the stack/configuration OP has chosen. Answering a question by proposing they use the stack/configuration you have chosen is a non-answer. There are likely reasons OP has chosen the configuration they chose, so an answer should assume this is the configuration they will use. For instance, maybe they don't want an API exposed to the internet, or they don't want to manage multiple repositories (and why should they have to). Plenty of valid reasons.